# cpprestsdk http_client constructor errors

Tags: c++, rest, constructor, null, cpprest-sdk

I use the code below in two different, independent projects.

```
auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();

    // Open stream to output file.
    pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html"))

        .then([=](ostream outFile)
        {
            *fileStream = outFile;


            // Create http_client to send the request.
            http_client client(U("http://www.bing.com/"));

            // Build request URI and start the request.
            uri_builder builder(U("/search"));

            builder.append_query(U("q"), U("cpprestsdk github"));

            return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());
        })

        // Handle response headers arriving.
        .then([=](http_response response)
        {
            printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

            // Write response body into the file.
            return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
        })

        // Close the file stream.
        .then([=](size_t)
        {
            return fileStream->close();
            })
        ;

        // Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
        try
        {
            requestTask.wait();
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
        }
```

Project 1: is a bigger one with other things
Project 2: one just contains the code below

when I compile and run Project 2 no errors occur and the code works perfectly fine, but if I compile Project 1 it compiles without errors, but at runtime an error occurs at `uri_builder builder(U("/search"));` which says:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF643034EE7 in Sgimri_TC2_V2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violence for read at position 0x0000000000000000.
(I translated that from German to English)

this error occurs in xstring here:

```
public:
    basic_string(const basic_string& _Right)
        : _Mypair(_One_then_variadic_args_t{}, _Alty_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(_Right._Getal())) {
        auto&& _Alproxy = _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Getal());
        _Container_proxy_ptr<_Alty> _Proxy(_Alproxy, _Mypair._Myval2);
        _Construct_lv_contents(_Right);
        _Proxy._Release();
    }
```

specifically the error occurs in this line `_Construct_lv_contents(_Right);`

It has to do with the constructor of the `uri_builder` where some components are NULL.
Something similar happend in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115040/crash-inside-http-client-constructor-casablanca-sdk), but I don't know how to solve it.

Does anyone hase a solution, hint or adivce which my help me? Would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem on my own. Here is a short way on how I solved the problem.

I used MS Visual Studio 2019 and compiled my project as `x64, Release` Version. After changing it to `x64, Debug` and changed project settings in *Project Properties* -> *C/C++ Code Genereation* -> *Runtime Library* to *Multithreaded-Debug-DLL(/MDd)* it compiles and runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

To save anyone else spending as much time on this issue as I have.

I just ran into an issue where something changed the configuration for my debug builds to Release.

Properties, Configuration\vcpkg\Vcpkg configuration